# Cypress - reverse each

Tags: jquery, each, cypress

I need to reverse taking element from array. I have to start from the last one. I can't find any different solution to use in Cypress than jQuery 'reverse' but I have problem to use it.

Don't work in both way:

```
 cy.get('.btn-remove.action.delete').reverse().each(($el, index, $list) =>  {
                        cy.get($el).click({force:true})
                       cy.wait(1000)
                })
```

answer from Cypress - TypeError: cy.get(...).reverse is not a function

And

```
cy.get('.btn-remove.action.delete').invoke('reverse').each(($el, index, $list) =>  {
                        cy.get($el).click({force:true})
                        cy.wait(1000)
                })
```

answer from Cypress - CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.invoke() errored because the property: 'reverse' does not exist on your subject.

Or maybe there is different way than reverse()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about trying with for loop and iterating from the end, using [eq()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html):

```
cy.get('.btn-remove.action.delete').its('length').then((numberOfItems) => {
  for (var i = numberOfItems-1; i>=0; i--) {
    cy.get('.btn-remove.action.delete').eq(i).click({force:true})
  }
})
```

Maybe it is not the cleanest way, but should work.

Not sure what was the cy.wait(1000) for in your code, but it shouldn't be necessary here. [(Actually, you should avoid using cy.wait() as much as possible)](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Unnecessary-Waiting)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes, maybe it's not the cleanest way but it works perfect. Thank you very much :)

Comment: I'm surprice there is not a cleaner way of doing this

Comment: there should be a cleaner solution .each() method

Comment: The main issue I'm seen with .each solution is that the $collection is coming in as a normal HTML element [] instead of JQuery<HTMLElement>. Why? Because for some reason I'm getting failing test using .innerHTML, and .value that replaces .val(), and .text()

Answer (score 2):

You can apply `reverse()` like this

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="sections"] > optgroup > option')
  .then($options => $options.get().reverse())
  .each($option => {                                    // reverse order
    ...
  })
```

Note the reverse method is `Array.reverse()` so you need to precede it with jQuery `.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

the eq solution implemented with .each()

```
cy.get('[data-cy="sections"] > optgroup > option').each(
      (_$option, index, $list) => {
        const firstIndex = 0;
        const lastIndex = $list.length - 1;
        const descendingIndex = lastIndex - index;

         cy.wrap($list).eq(descendingIndex).click({force:true})
     
      }
    );
```

Cons:

- $list: HTMLElement[] instead of JQuery<HTMLElement[]>

  - We have to use javascript to get access the $list
  - We cannot use $list[descendingIndex].text() or $list[descendingIndex].val()
  - Instead we can use $list.innerHTML, $list.[descendingIndex].click() or ($list).value

I recommend to use cy.wrap($list).(cypress command) for actions
and if we need access to some string, number, or value, use javascript to get it from the $list.